# https timeouts on AWS elastic beanstalk app

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We're having a bizarre issue on one of our Elastic Beanstalk apps, where every https connection results in a timeout. Verified that the cert itself is fine via `openssl s_client`, so it looks like an issue with the load balancer - but everything reads fine there too, so I'm a little stumped.

We're not using Route 53 (managing DNS over on namecheap) and our cert was purchased externally (not using AWS cert manager).

My main questions are:

- I don't have access to our Namecheap account but I've been assured everything is in line over there - am I on the right track by focusing on the load balancer/aws config as the culprit, or does this sound like it could be some weird DNS misconfiguration?
- Are there good reasons to avoid using the AWS cert manager when not managing DNS via route 53? If using an AWS-supplied cert could resolve this, I'm happy to go that route instead. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513512/aws-elastic-beanstalk-namecheap-ssl-configuration) question is very similar but deals with AWS-supplied certs.

Comment: Sounds like one of your security groups is not configured properly. Another issue I've seen often is pointing the load balancer to port 443 of your instance. You should still point it to port 80 and have it use HTTP.

Answer (score 19):

Maybe you are pointing Load Balancer to port 443 + HTTPS instead of 80 + HTTP? Try setting up Classic Load Balancer as shown on the pictures.

Example 1
[image: Example 1]

Example 2
[image: Example 2]

Comment: Worked perfectly for me.

Comment: should we also enable 443 ??  Is there a security implication to this vs having the 443 port open on the docker container?

Answer (score 0):

There are two places to enable https on elastic beanstalk:

Place 1: From elastic beanstalk environment

- select Services
- select Elastic Beanstalk
- select the environment within the application
- select Configuration
- in Load balancer section: select modify
- select "Add listener" with the following info:

  ```
  listener port: 443
  listener protocol: HTTPS
  Instance port: 80
  Instance protocol: HTTP
  SSL certificate: Add an ACM certificate created from AWS or another
  ```

Place 2: The load balancer

- select Services
- select EC2
- scroll down left panel: select Load balancers
- select Action
- select Edit Listeners
- select "Add listener" with the following info:

  ```
  listener port: 443
  listener protocol: HTTPS
  Instance port: 80
  Instance protocol: HTTP
  SSL certificate: Add an ACM certificate created from AWS or another
  ```
- select Save